# extracting paragraph using search string

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine

i am using the below code for extracting paragraph for matching string.

```
int charBeforeAndAfter = 100;
        string matchParagraphs = string.Empty;
                        Regex wordMatch = new Regex(@"\b" + word + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (string paragraph in text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                int startIdx = -1;
                int length = -1;
                foreach (Match match in wordMatch.Matches(paragraph))
                {
                    int wordIdx = match.Index;
                    if (wordIdx >= startIdx && wordIdx <= startIdx + length)
                        continue;
                    startIdx = wordIdx > charBeforeAndAfter ? wordIdx - charBeforeAndAfter : 0;
                    length = wordIdx + match.Length + charBeforeAndAfter < paragraph.Length ? match.Length + charBeforeAndAfter : paragraph.Length - startIdx;
                    string extract = wordMatch.Replace(paragraph.Substring(startIdx, length), "<b>" + match.Value + "</b>");
                    matchParagraphs = "..." + extract + "...";
                    return matchParagraphs;
                }
            }
```

i am getting correct result,but i am getting breakable words in starting and ending paragraphs like  **"...ing regions uses the and Boolean connector to specify the region so narr..."**

how to avoid that breaking words.. plz help me

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to achieve?

Comment: here **boolean** is the search key word, so im reading 30chars before and after the key word **boolean**.. OUTPUT:- **"...ing regions uses the and Boolean connector to specify the region so narr..."** here my words are broken while reading 30chars,this the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static class Program {

    static void Main(params string[] args) {

        string text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea 
commodo consequat.";

        ExtractParagraph(text, "magna");
        ExtractParagraph(text, "ipsum");
        ExtractParagraph(text, "ut");

    }

    static void ExtractParagraph(string text, string word) {
        Console.WriteLine("Matches for: {0}", word);
        string expression = @"((^.{0,30}|\w*.{30})\b" + word + @"\b(.{30}\w*|.{0,30}$))";
        Regex wordMatch = new Regex(expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match m in wordMatch.Matches(text)) {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", m.Value);
        }
    }

}
```

The basic idea is to match extra stuff around the word: `.*{30}\bword\b.*{30}` and then add some "word characters" not to cut the word in half: `\w*.*{30}\bword\b.*{30}\w*`.

The pieces like `^.{0,30}` and . `.{0,30}$` are to match even if there are less than 30 characters from the beginning or end of the sentence.

As always with regular expressions, this is unlikely to win a readability contest, but it seems to work...

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem.  I solved it by using this:

```
int len = 50;
int length = 50;    
while (text.substring(0, length).length == length)

{
    if (text.substring(0, length).endsWith(" "))
    {
            var out = 'what you want to output'
            break
    }
    else
    {
            length--;
            if (length < 10) break;
    }
}
return out;
```

It isn't the best solution but it works well for my needs.  Basically it just runs through my code and checks to see if it under 50 characters.  And prints anything under 50 and where the last thing is a space.